# What does the `width` field mean in PostgreSQL's EXPLAIN?

Tags: sql, postgresql

For example, from [the EXPLAIN documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/using-explain.html):

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM tenk1;

                         QUERY PLAN
-------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on tenk1  (cost=0.00..458.00 rows=10000 width=244)
```

What does `width=244` mean?

Comment: Person who downvoted: what's up? A little constructive criticism would be appreciated.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

This is the "Estimated average width (in bytes) of rows output by this plan node"

Basically each row returned will be 244 bytes.

See [Explain](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) for more details.

Comment: Ah, it looks like [the documentation for 8.1](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-explain.html) (which I was reading) does not explain the meaning of width, but [the documentation for 8.3](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/using-explain.html) (which you linked to) does. That would explain why I didn't notice it.

Comment: @DavidWolever: you should not read the manual of outdated versions. Read the manual that corresponds to **your** version. Btw: 8.3 is going to be de-supported as well soon, so if you really use that you should prepare to update as soon as possible. Preferrably to 9.1

Comment: Lesson learned. I won't be grabbing the first version Google hands me in the future.

Comment: Pro tip: Always use the postgresql version you use in queries to google :).